# R Running out of memory over large file

Tags: r, data.table

I had a unique problem yesterday when trying to read a large .csv file into memory.
the file itself is 9GB with a bit more than 80 Million rows and 10 columns.
it loaded perfectly and took up around 7GB in memory using a remote machine with 128GB of RAM.
my problem is, i want to work on the data with a local machine that only has 32GB of RAM.
i tried reading it with `data.table::fread` but **R** crahes when it uses all of the machine's memory.

is there a safer way of reading the data that won't crash **R**?
is this a known issue? can something be wrong with the machine?
both machine are running windows 7 enterprise.

## EDIT:

saving and reading the data in an RDS file worked, but i still want to be able to use just one computer for the entire job.
is there any other way to read the data directly from the csv file?
i don't want to report a bug in data.table unless i am sure this is an issue with `fread` and not a local issue.

any other ideas?

Comment: what version of data.table are you on? try installing the development version

Comment: also please report here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2073

Comment: You could also save the data table on your remote machine as a .RData file, copy it to your local machine, and load it there

Comment: data.table version 1.10.4-3 on both.

Comment: @HongOoi saved it in a RDS file and it loaded, but i still want to be able to read is straight from the csv.